# OpenWRT print to console in preinit scripts

Tags: openwrt

Does anybody know how to print out the message inside the OpenWRT preinit scripts? I tried with echo but all messages are suppressed.

Comment: Before preinit_essentials runs (specifically init_console) I would think you would need some form of debugger attached.  After that, you should have console (as init_console sets up std{in,out,err} to the right ps).

Comment: Hi @bishop, I have the serial port connects to the board all the time. We can see the Linux kernel boot log, do not know why after the `preinit` script starts, it sets up something that redirects all the script output to somewhere

Comment: choose_console (just before init_console) is supposed to pick the right device.  Do you see "Continuing with Regular Preinit" on your serial?  Also, instead of echo try preinit_net_echo "whatever"

Comment: Hi @bishop, thank a lot for your answer, preinit_echo and preinit_net_echo are what exactly I need. We can print to console by calling these functions.

Comment: Great! I've answered for posterity (please accept when you can).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preinit_echo` and `preinit_net_echo` to output to the connected console.  Use both, to cover both a local and a networked console, like:

```
preinit_echo "Message here"
preinit_net_echo "Message here"
```

(For discussion, see comments on OP.)